# How to find minimum date from 3 dates using javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I want to find minimum date from 3 dates (8/1/2011,6/1/2011,7/1/2011) format is (mm/dd/yyyy) using java script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested code, but you should get the idea!

```
// Initialise an array of dates, with correct values
// You want 3 dates, so put them in here
var MyDates= New Array('15/10/2000','28/05/1999','17/09/2005');

// A function that takes an array of dates as its input
// and returns the smallest (earliest) date
// MUST take at LEAST 2 dates or will throw an error!
function GetSmallestDate(DateArray){

    var SmallestDate = new Date(DateArray[0]);
    for(var i = 1; i < DateArray.length; i++)
    {
        var TempDate = new Date(DateArray[i]);
        if(TempDate < SmallestDate)
            SmallestDate  = TempDate ;
    }
    return SmallestDate ;
}

// Call the function!
alert(GetSmallestDate(MyDates));
```

Comment: You can't compare strings this way, you'll need `Date` object or at least string in `YYYY/MM/DD` format.

Comment: @Marcel thanks, I've changed it now should work, it's all untested though

Comment: This is a lot better, but still not quite robust: if you feed `Date` a string, you're stuck with an implementation-dependent method for [date parsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse); you'd better use a method like Rudie uses, where you feed `Date` three parameters (converted to numbers).

Answer (score 3):

Convert the dates to int, use Math.min to find the smallest:

```
var dates = ['8/1/2011', '6/1/2011', '7/1/2011']; // dates
dates = dates.map(function(d) {
  d=d.split('/');
  return new Date(d[2], parseInt(d[0])-1, d[1]).getTime();
}); // convert
var minDate = new Date(Math.min.apply(null, dates)); // smallest > Date
```

Comment: +1 for using `apply`, indeed more neat than my solution. But bare in mind that `Array.map` isn't support in many browsers, yet (no IE < 9).

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Return the timestamp of a MM/DD/YYYY date
 */
function getTime(date) {
  var tmp = date.split('/');
  var d = new Date(tmp[2], parseInt(tmp[0])-1, tmp[1]);
  return d.getTime();
}
// then return the output: getTime('6/7/2000') < getTime('6/7/2001')
```

See [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for details. If you are a jQuery UI user, you might find their [date parsing method](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) helpful.

Comment: Use `Math.min.apply(null, dates)` to get the smallest time.