# How to get nearest value from Array?

Tags: javascript

I have Array like this:

```
var array = [{top: 5, left: 50}, {top: 12, left: 44}, {top: 60, left: 11}]
```

I need find in this array **only one** nearest `top` and `left` if I know:

```
var findNearest = {top:10, left:40}; //never be bigger than +5 (or lower than -5)
```

For example in this case it should return the second because `top: 12` is near `top:10` in my `findNearest` object and difference isn't bigger that 5. Same thing for left.

How?

**Edit**

My idea is create `for` loop and checking every object if have the same value as object what I want to find. If no, repeat `for` loop with increased value `+1`.

Example of **my bad idea**:

```
var increaseTop = true;
var increaseLeft = true;

function find(obj){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].top == obj.top){
            // found nearest .top, not increase by 1
            increaseTop = false;
        }
        if(array[i].left == obj.left){
            // found nearest .left, not increase by 1
            increaseLeft = false;
        }
    } 
    // here repeat for loop if is increaseLeft OR increaseTop is true
    // with increased values .top and .left
}

findNearest({top:10, left:40});
```

Comment: Can you show us an attempt at solving this please?

Comment: Here is a similar question. You just have to modify the solution a bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728746/how-to-find-minimum-date-from-3-dates-using-javascript-function

Comment: I do not know how it could work, so I ask

Comment: I dont know what is bad on my question but sorry

Comment: The issue is lack of effort and example of what you tried.

Comment: @mplungjan I edited my question, adding as I thought it might work

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I'm just learning this Angular stuff and am in need of help with trying to use the @Turf package. Can you give me a few pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calculate each distance and get min:

```js
var array = [{top: 5, left: 50}, {top: 12, left: 44}, {top: 60, left: 11}]
var findNearest = getNearest({top:10, left:40}, array);
console.log(findNearest);
function getDistance(p1, p2) {
  var a = p2.top - p1.top;
  var b = p2.left - p1.left;
  return Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
}

function getNearest(point, points) {
  var min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
      minIndex;
  var dist;
  for(var i = 0 ; i < points.length; i++) {
    dist = getDistance(point, points[i]);
    if(dist < min) {
      min = dist;
      minIndex = i;
    }
  }
  return points[minIndex];
}
```